# EF Core repeatedly creating same migration, altering identity column and changing nothing

Tags: entity-framework-migrations, ef-core-2.2

Recently I added a new data entity to my EFCore2.2 DbContext (within a net47 project) and attempted to generate a migration with the CLI tool as I have many times. On attempting to update the database the migration fails since the migration attempts to ALTER COLUMN on an identity column in an unrelated table. I removed the migration and removed the new entity and then ran **add-migration**, essentially with zero code changes. Sure enough, the same breaking AlterColumn calls, and nothing else, were generated (pointlessly, it seems) in the Up & Down methods. Here is the migration code:

```cs
public partial class ServerConfig : Migration
{
    protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<long>(
            name: "ID",
            table: "ProfileParams", 
            nullable: false,
            oldClrType: typeof(long))
            .OldAnnotation("SqlServer:ValueGenerationStrategy", SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn);
    }

    protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<long>(
            name: "ID",
            table: "ProfileParams",
            nullable: false,
            oldClrType: typeof(long))
            .Annotation("SqlServer:ValueGenerationStrategy", SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn);
    }
}
```

In the interest of eliminating extra factors, I reverted code back to just *after* this entity (ProfileParams) was originally added & migrations created. I tried **add-migration** from that point, and indeed, I got the same migration code as we see above (and no change in snapshot).  I then reverted code back to just *before* the ProfileParams class was added, and generated the migration that actually *created* that table. It was identical to the full CREATE, and the snapshot was changed appropriately. But then I *immediately* ran **add-migration** again. Lo and behold I get the same extra "alter column" migration as above, and the next migration & the next will have it.

So essentially, going forward, it appears all future migrations will have this same "alter column" added in the up/down methods. Why?

In the interest of additional detail:

- Various other tables have an ProfileParams navigation property which
  EFCore picked up as a nullable foreign key.
- Abbreviated bits of the snapshot:

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity("ProfileParams", b =>
{
    b.Property<long>("ID")
        .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
    b.HasKey("ID");
    b.ToTable("ProfileParams");
});

modelBuilder.Entity("AssetUser", b =>
{
    b.Property<string>("ID");
    b.Property<long?>("ParamsID");
    b.HasKey("ID");
    b.HasIndex("ParamsID");
    b.ToTable("AssetUsers");
});

modelBuilder.Entity("AssetUser", b =>
{
    b.HasOne("ProfileParams", "Params")
        .WithMany()
        .HasForeignKey("ParamsID");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have NuGet package for only one provider.
I had (beside MSSQL) also MySql and Postgresql and it used the wrong one when using AddMigration.

Comment: It's true in my case. Both SqlServer and Npgsql are added. Specifying `<PROVIDER>` argument helped.

Comment: This was the cause of my issue. I had referenced EFCore.BulkExtensions which in turn referenced other provider libs. I fixed it by add (1,1) to the UseIdentityColumn method call, which seemed to be enough to get it to use the correct one.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is due to using `uint` for a primary key, and what looks like a bug in EF Core trying silently to work around this, and then silently failing in an obscure way.

In the case above, despite my detail I did not show the original entity class, but the ID in question was indeed of type `uint`. Answers to other questions suggest that EF Core does not support unsigned types, but it will certainly **pretend** to, and create a confusing situation such as this one! Instead of having an error on the initial migration (which does not apply the needed annotation for SQL auto-identity), it goes ahead and creates it.

This is what we would expect if the entity class simply had an ID of type `long`:

```cs
migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
    name: "ProfileParams",
    columns: table => new
    {
        ID = table.Column<long>(nullable: false)
/* But this part is missing when uint type is used! */
            .Annotation("SqlServer:ValueGenerationStrategy", SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn), 
    },
    constraints: table =>
    {
        table.PrimaryKey("PK_ProfileParams", x => x.ID);
    });
```

From there, and forever onward, on all future migrations it will attempt to fix its own omission by altering the column with the annotation. Oddly, though, even the "Down" function it generates suggests it *already had* the annotation since Up & Down are identical! But original migration and snapshot, and all subsequent snapshots fail to capture what the following migrations try to fix.

Presumably if the migration were tweaked and the table were actually dropped and recreated (not sure why EF Core thinks it can alter an identity column!) then the resulting SQL table would then have an auto-identity `bigint` key, but there would likely be issues populating the actual `uint` ID field from that value.

In short, just use a long key and it works. Wow.